# ajax requested page network status shows as pending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, e-commerce

I have developed a e-commerce website. I have a index page and a products page.
index page has header menu like home, grocery etc. if i click on grocery href link it loads the products(all the related products related to grocery) page to the index through the ajax method, so only few contents of the page is changed. after navigating to the grocery link, in products page i have made a product filter for the brand and the category. but my problem is my filter is working very fast in the products page, but if we navigate through the header menu several times again and again example grocery->household>cleaning accessories the products page starts to hang and if open network status it shows the page as pending

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle url" data-toggle="dropdown" data-category="Grocery">Grocery</a>
```

ajax function

```
$(function()

        {
            $('.url').click(function(event)
            {               
            //alert("sdsdsd dfd");  

            event.preventDefault();
            var url1 = $(this).data("category");
            var url2 = $(this).data("parent");
            var url3 = $(this).data("subcategory");
            var url4 = $(this).data("childcategory");
            //alert(url1);
             $(".overlay").show();
            $.ajax({
                      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/Products",
                      method:"POST",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data:{catname:url1,parent:url2,sub:url3,child:url4},
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                             //alert(data.page);
                             $('#body').html(data.page);
                        },

                          complete: function(){
                            $(".overlay").hide();
                          }


            });
        });
    }
    );
```

This is how i return response back to ajax from controller

```
$page['page'] = $this->load->view('products', $data, true);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($page));
```

please click on the link and let me know the solution for it

https://www.frocerie.com/demo/

note : currently u can navigate grocery -> household>cleaning aceesories

Comment: What does the view look like for this, I don't think you need a view for Ajax, just an array of data to return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter ajax, handling server response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207654/codeigniter-ajax-handling-server-response-data)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ok...but how can i receive response in ajax ?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix bro i really need yur help

Comment: i have several div in products page example brand div have the list of brands and category div has the list of category and in right hand side it displays the list of products image, name price etc. how to bind the response data to these divs?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to send back.  You have to pick, you can send HTML / JSON or  HTML inside of the JSON.  But, you cant send the JSON inside of the HTML.  So probably what you have now is half HTML and half JASON

Comment: For example what else is in `$page` ?

Comment: i have a view(products page) in $page. so that i can simply do like this in ajax success function  success:function(data)
         {
          // alert(data.page);
           $('#body').html(data.page);
          },

Comment: Why not just send it back as HTML, not JSON.

Comment: u mean like this $this->load->view('products',$data);

Comment: Yea that should work, then just use `data` in the AJAX callback becuase it's already HTML.  There should be no problem return HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending it back as HTML, there is no issue putting HTML in the response to a request.

```
$page['page'] = $this->load->view('products', $data, true);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output($page['page']);
```

To send just HTML back,

```
$this->load->view('products', $data);
```

Then you have to change your success:

```
 success:function(data)
 {
     $('#body').html(data);
 },
```

If you want to see how long it takes to encode it as json you can do this

```
$time = microtime(true);
json_encode($page['page']);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) * 0.001;
```

Basically get the microtime ( time in milliseconds ), run the function, then get the subtract the current time from the start time.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

**UPDATE**

IF you go here and put your stuff in ( wish I could save the page )

https://www.hurl.it/

Then select "Post" and add in your url and your request data as parameters

```
catname:Grocery
parent:Household
sub:Cleaning Accessories
```

You can see what the response is.  You can also check this in the network tab or the browser console  ( usually f12 )

I can also tell your running PHP 5.4.45  :)

For extra credit once you get it working you can try this ( sometimes it messes up javasript, mostly if you have inline comments  `//` )

```
 function minify( $text ){
    $search = array(
    /*you could try this
             '/\s\/\/.+/', //strip inline comments - //comments
     */
            '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
            '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
            '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
       /*
           '',
       */
            '>',
            '<',
            '\\1'
    );

    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);

    return $text;
}
```

But it will strip out most the whitespace an make your response a bit smaller.

Comment: but does these 2 codes makes any differents in page load time? i mean which one do you think more faster

Comment: Probably strait HTML, but it wont be by much.  Think about it, your not encoding it as Json and then Parsing it from Json.  So the time it takes to do that is the time difference.

Comment: if we try the jscon encoded method and bind the value to the particular div wil be also fine?    $.each(data, function(index,value){
            //process your data by index, in example
            $("#catlang_name").val(value.catlang_name);
        });

Comment: I doubt it, it should have worked the way you had it, but there may be something in there that is messing up the JSON,